# Splitting Expression by the comparison operator but keep delimiter

Tags: php, regex

Sadly this is another regex question because it just evades my mental capacity for some reason.

I'm running a foreach loop on an array like the following

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "(1+1)+1=2*2"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "2+3<=4"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "(2+3)>=4"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "2+3<>4"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "2+3<4"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "2+3>4"
  [6]=>
  string(9) "(2+3)+3=8"
}
```

I'm trying to split it up by the comparison operator but keep the operator.  TO give you an example of what I'm after I'll take key `[0]` and make an output array.

```
array(){
    [0]=>
    string() "(1+1)+1"
    [1]=>
    string() "="
    [2]=>
    string() "2*2"
}
```

here's what I've got so far but it's not getting the operator

`preg_match_all( "~(^[()|\d|+|-|*|/]+(=)([()|\d|+|-|*|/]))~", $expression, $expression_parts );`

Thanks in advance

Comment: And spliting `(2+3)>=4` should show what?

Comment: it should be like this
`(2+3)`
`>=`
`4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spare a lot of convolution by calling `preg_split()` and isolating just the comparison operators.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bPLnZ))

```
$strings = [
    "(1+1)+1=2*2",
    "2+3<=4",
    "(2+3)>=4",
    "2+3<>4",
    "2+3<4",
    "2+3>4",
    "(2+3)+3=8"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(preg_split('~([<>=]+)~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '(1+1)+1',
  1 => '=',
  2 => '2*2',
)
array (
  0 => '2+3',
  1 => '<=',
  2 => '4',
)
array (
  0 => '(2+3)',
  1 => '>=',
  2 => '4',
)
array (
  0 => '2+3',
  1 => '<>',
  2 => '4',
)
array (
  0 => '2+3',
  1 => '<',
  2 => '4',
)
array (
  0 => '2+3',
  1 => '>',
  2 => '4',
)
array (
  0 => '(2+3)+3',
  1 => '=',
  2 => '8',
)
```

Explanation:

`preg_split()` is the versatile regex version of `explode()`. The pattern tells the function every instance where an explosion should occur.

```
~          #Pattern delimiter
(          #Start capture group
[<>=]+     #Match (as much as possible) one or more comparison symbols
)          #End capture group
~          #Pattern delimiter
```

The pattern alone doesn't work as required -- flags must be declared on this function call.

Parameter 3 is `0`: this tells the `preg_split()` to match an unlimited number of times. This is the default behavior of the function, but for parameter 4 to work we need to use this placeholder.

Parameter 4 is `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` : This tells the function to retain the substrings that are used as "points of explosion". Without this flag, the output array would not contain the comparison symbols. If we weren't going to use this flag, then the capture group brackets would be needless in the pattern.

---

Here are how `preg_split()`'s brothers would operate with positive and negated character classes:

```
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(preg_match('~([^<>=]+)([<>=]+)([^<>=]+)~', $string, $out) ? array_slice($out, 1) : []);
    echo "\n";
    var_export(preg_match_all('~[^<>=]+|[<>=]+~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
    echo "\n\n";
}
```